# add new json object if id match with json id of other using node js / javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes

```js
const data = [
    {
      system: {
        id: "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
      },
      DataDetails: {
        shortSlugOption: { "en-us": "some value", "za-op": "random value" },
        mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "some file", "za-op": "file Linl" },
        mediaFileAssetGalary: { hi: "file link 2" },
        singleMediaImage: { hi: "file link single", "en-us": "english link" },
        gallery: {
          "za-op": [
            {
              conf: {
                type: "media",
                id: "01",
              },
            },
            {
              conf: {
                type: "media",
                id: "10",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        mediaAccess: {
          hi: {
            conf: {
              type: "media",
              id: "01",
            },
          }, 
          en: {
            conf: {
              type: "media",
              id: "1000",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      system: {
        id: "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "Author" } },
      },
      DataDetails: {
        short: { "en-us": ["shorts", "values"], "za-op": "short details" },
        shortSlugOption: { "hi-In": "options" },
        booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
        entryDetails: {
          "hi-In": [
            {
              conf: {
                type: "entry",
                id: "100",
              },
            },
            {
              conf: {
                type: "entry",
                id: "34",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
        singleEntry: {
          "en-us": {
            conf: {
              type: "entry",
              id: "34",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      system: {
        id: "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
      },
      DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "details value" } },
    },
    {
      system: {
        id: "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "new" } },
      },
      DataDetails: {
        oneReference: { hi: "values 1" },
        multiReference: { "hi-In": "values 2" },
        media: {
          hi: {
            conf: {
              type: "media",
              id: "01",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      system: {
        id: "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "new" } },
      },
      DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "hi-IN": "jksdsdo" } },
    },
    {
      system: {
        id: "7kRzyt4PFrX13gHcw3Z1Ko",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "testing" } },
      },
      DataDetails: { testingNewValue: { "en-us": "kknksdo" } },
    },
    {
      system: {
        id: "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
      },
      DataDetails: {
        short: { "za-op": "dfvndkssa" },
        shortSlugOption: { hi: "sdocjosmdc" },
        mediaFileAssetLink: { "en-us": "jdsojocis" },
        booleanField: { "hi-In": "true" },
      },
    },
    {
      system: {
        id: "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
      },
      DataDetails: {
        dummy: { "en-us": "dshcifdvk" },
        india: { "za-op": "sdci", hi: "hewd" },
      },
    },
    {
      system: {
        id: "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw",
        type: "Entry",
        content: { type: { name: "dummy" } },
      },
      DataDetails: {
        testingNewValue: { "en-us": "sdcoklsdc" },
        locationField: { hi: "sdcndkdc" },
      },
    },
  ],
  result = data.reduce(
    (
      r,
      {
        system: {
          id,
          content: {
            type: { name },
          },
        },
        DataDetails,
      }
    ) => {
      r[name] ??= {};
      Object.entries(DataDetails).forEach(([key, object]) => {
        Object.entries(object).forEach(([loc, value]) => {
          r[name][loc] ??= {};
          r[name][loc][id] ??= {};
          if (typeof value !== "object") {
            r[name][loc][id][key] = value;
          } else {
            console.log(value);
          }
        });
      });
      return r;
    },
    {}
  );

console.log(result)
```

In the above output I am trying to replace the media with the below object as the below code is for the media
I want to match the id which is present inside the data output and replace the json with the mediaObj matching id

```
let mediaObj = {
  "01": {
    status: true,
    tag: [],
    filename: "exute-image.jpg",
    is_dir: false,
    parent_uid: null,
  },
  "02": {
    status: true,
    tag: [],
    filename: "wallpapers-6.jpg",
    is_dir: false,
    parent_uid: null,
  },
  "10": {
    status: true,
    tag: [],
    filename: "in-space-rk.jpg",
    is_dir: false,
    parent_uid: null,
  },
  "25": {
    status: true,
    tag: [],
    filename: "justice-league.jpg",
    is_dir: false,
    parent_uid: null,
  },
  "67": {
    status: true,
    tag: [],
    filename: "batman.jpg",
    is_dir: false,
    parent_uid: null,
  },
};
```

so my expected output is like this when I run my program

### Expected Value

```
{
  "Author": {
    "en-us": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "shortSlugOption": "some value",
        "mediaFileAssetLink": "some file",
        "singleMediaImage": "english link"
      },
      "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5": {}
    },
    "za-op": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "shortSlugOption": "random value",
        "mediaFileAssetLink": "file Linl"
      },
      "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5": {
        "short": "short details",
        "gallery": [
          {
            "status": true,
            "tag": [],
            "filename": "exute-image.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "parent_uid": null
          },
          {
            "status": true,
            "tag": [],
            "filename": "in-space-rk.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "parent_uid": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "hi": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "mediaFileAssetGalary": "file link 2",
        "singleMediaImage": "file link single",
        "mediaAccess": [
          {
            "status": true,
            "tag": [],
            "filename": "exute-image.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "parent_uid": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "hi-In": {
      "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5": {
        "shortSlugOption": "options",
        "booleanField": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

as the id get changed and I want to match every-time with the `mediaObj` json and replace the value if there is multiple or single media file exits but if the media id does not match with `mediaObj` then it should delete the that json as you can see in `mediaAccess` id `1000` does not match with the `mediaObj` so it should delete it

as the same applies with the entries if I get the media replace code then I can try with the entry code too

Comment: It's unclear what you think the problem is: "the output" is an array of arrays. Where/how are you looking at the output, and what makes you think it's "wrong"?

Comment: What is the use case you are trying to solve, since arrays need to be stored inside a data structure. You can convert them to strings ( JSON.stringify(res[0])+JSON.stringify(res[1])) and apply custom regex to use it.

Comment: Hello @DaveNewton i update my question i hope its now understandable ? :)

Comment: It isn't; where/how are you looking at the output, and what makes you think it's wrong? If you want to generate a CSV then you need to iterate over your `map`ped array and create CSV from each entry.

Comment: You should reduce the example: there is a lot of data in it that is unrelated to your question. Secondly, you should show your efforts. What is the problem you encounter? Where is your code? Finally, you have completely re-edited the question which is nothing like the first version of the question. What's all that about? Oh, and that is not JSON. Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: you've mentioned `media`, but I noticed that you have `type: "entry"` which has not been mentioned in your example. Is it also checked with `mediaObj` or only `media` type?

Comment: I have not added entry json bcoz mediaObj and entryObj have similar json data but with different data like I have mention if I get one solution of media I can reuse that same code for entry too @NickVu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

Replace

```
          } else {
            console.log(value);
          }
```

with this:

```
        } else {
          const newValues = Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(replacePossibleConf) : [ replacePossibleConf(value) ];
          if (newValues.filter(e => e != null).length > 0) {
            r[name][loc][id][key] = newValues;
          }
        }
```

and add the function:

```
function replacePossibleConf(possibleConf) {
  return mediaObj[possibleConf?.conf?.id];
}
```

Which gives output very close to what you were asking:

```
{
  "Author": {
    "en-us": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "shortSlugOption": "some value",
        "mediaFileAssetLink": "some file",
        "singleMediaImage": "english link"
      },
      "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5": {}
    },
    "za-op": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "shortSlugOption": "random value",
        "mediaFileAssetLink": "file Linl",
        "gallery": [
          {
            "status": true,
            "tag": [],
            "filename": "exute-image.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "parent_uid": null
          },
          {
            "status": true,
            "tag": [],
            "filename": "in-space-rk.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "parent_uid": null
          }
        ]
      },
      "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5": {
        "short": "short details"
      }
    },
    "hi": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "mediaFileAssetGalary": "file link 2",
        "singleMediaImage": "file link single",
        "mediaAccess": [
          {
            "status": true,
            "tag": [],
            "filename": "exute-image.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "parent_uid": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "en": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {}
    },
    "hi-In": {
      "1aBOO8tu3lUsjtICuIbUM5": {
        "shortSlugOption": "options",
        "booleanField": "true"
      }
    }
  },
  "testing": {
    "en-us": {
      "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA": {
        "testingNewValue": "details value"
      },
      "7kRzyt4PFrX13gHcw3Z1Ko": {
        "testingNewValue": "kknksdo"
      }
    }
  },
  "new": {
    "hi": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "oneReference": "values 1",
        "media": [
          {
            "status": true,
            "tag": [],
            "filename": "exute-image.jpg",
            "is_dir": false,
            "parent_uid": null
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "hi-In": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "multiReference": "values 2"
      }
    },
    "hi-IN": {
      "cIb5mqEBRWDD6hrNmFmFE": {
        "testingNewValue": "jksdsdo"
      }
    }
  },
  "dummy": {
    "za-op": {
      "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz": {
        "short": "dfvndkssa"
      },
      "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy": {
        "india": "sdci"
      }
    },
    "hi": {
      "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz": {
        "shortSlugOption": "sdocjosmdc"
      },
      "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy": {
        "india": "hewd"
      },
      "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw": {
        "locationField": "sdcndkdc"
      }
    },
    "en-us": {
      "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz": {
        "mediaFileAssetLink": "jdsojocis"
      },
      "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy": {
        "dummy": "dshcifdvk"
      },
      "7hbdS3MgfZ73TOtlu1WfXw": {
        "testingNewValue": "sdcoklsdc"
      }
    },
    "hi-In": {
      "2OspeCtNK0sh2cPiuU9jIz": {
        "booleanField": "true"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro... You're asking a very simple question in a really complex way...
I am not 100% sure what you are asking and what data you want to replace with what... but I'll try my best :)

When you receive the data in JSON format, you will have to manipulate it into a JS object that you can extract data from

```
let parsedData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))
```

This will allow you to easily access keys and values within the data you received
After that, you can build a constructor function that builds the new object for you, by accepting the received data object, that has been parsed, and the  data you want to replace the values within the data you receive

```
const constructNewData = (parsedData, replaceData) => {
    let newData = {};
    Object.keys(parsedData).forEach(key => {
        if (replaceData[key]) {
            newData[key] = replaceData[key];
        } else {
            newData[key] = parsedData[key];
        }
    });
    return newData;
}
```

You're going to want to do something like this. Map over the keys of your received data and replace the values if they match

If you can exactly explain which values you want to replace in your JSON data, I can help you further :)

Comment: for clear understanding you can see my `expected output` like where I have share how my output look like