# assign value by matching the json key and value of another json using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, nodes

I am trying to assign a json value by comparing the nested json object deeply

my first json object result look like this when I do console.log(result);

### result

```
{
  "computer": {
    "en": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "gallery": "Some value here",
        "dummykey": "some dummy value here"
      },
      "ksjdfsk123233165":{
        "gallery": "test value",
        "dummykey": "checking the new file here"
      }
    }
  },
  "testing": {
    "hi": {
      "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA": {
        "access": "not available",
        "final": "still in progress"
      }
    },
    "ja": {
      "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA": {
        "mediaaccess": "system check",
        "access": "available",
        "final": "done"
      },
      "sdjksd9120812nmdns9": {
        "access": "available",
        "final": "progress"
      }
    }
  },
  "hardware": {
    "us": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "fieldtest": null,
        "media": "not available"
      },
      "sjkjsp3253m899as0": {
        "fieldtest": null,
        "media": "not available"
      }
    },
    "eu": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "fieldtest": null,
        "media": "available"
      },
      "sjkjsp3253m899as0": {
        "fieldtest": "in test we are planning",
        "media": "not available"
      }
    }
  },
  "software": {
    "uk": {
      "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy": {
        "testfield": "its working",
        "assign": "not yet"
      },
      "wehjbe8230291929umsnd":{
        "testfield": "working",
        "assign": "new trainee"
      }
    }
  },
  "demo": {
    "ga": {
      "4zu7f2YP4cXqR6aeeMxEt8": {
        "newkey": "hello",
        "assign": "to new assignnie"
      },
      "ksdjfns4575634n":{
        "newkey": "working",
        "assign": "new trainee"
      }
    },
  }
};
```

the second json object which I am trying to compare and assign the value is below

### compareObj

```
{
  "computer": { "compare": "gallery" },
  "testing": { "compare": "mediaaccess" },
  "hardware": { "compare": "fieldtest" },
  "software": { "compare": "testfield" },
  "demo": { "compare": "assign" }
}
```

I am trying to check and assign the value which is present inside the `compareObj` object with the key which is present in side `result` obj and assign the value in compareValue

```
let compareValue;
```

but the problem is while assigning the value I want to check if the `compareObj` value is present inside the `result` obj or not

here in the first example result

```
"computer": {
    "en": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "gallery": "Some value here",
        "dummykey": "some dummy value here"
      }
    }
  },
```

and compareObj

```
 "computer": { "compare": "gallery" },
```

here compareObj contain the `compare` key which have `gallery` and the `result` obj contain `gallary` as a key so `compareValue` should contain the `compareValue= "Some value here"` like this

but
in the second example

```
 "testing": {
    "hi": {
      "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA": {
        "access": "not available",
        "final": "still in progress"
      }
    },
    "ja": {
      "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA": {
        "mediaaccess": "system check",
        "access": "available",
        "final": "done"
      }
    }
  },
```

and `compareObj`Obj

```
 "testing": { "compare": "mediaaccess" },
```

as testing hi does not contain the `mediaaccess` then it should check the other object which is ja and assign the value like this `compareValue="system check"`

3rd example result

```
  "hardware": {
    "us": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "fieldtest": null,
        "media": "not available"
      }
    },
    "eu": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "fieldtest": null,
        "media": "available"
      }
    }
  },
```

and compareObj

```
"hardware": { "compare": "fieldtest" },
```

if the value present in `compareObj` is not available inside the `result` obj or the value contain is null then it should look like this `compareValue= "Untitled"`

if the object contain multiple value then it should take value from the first object for eg in 2nd example the `mediaaccess` is not present so it should take from 2nd language or the 3rd language or the 4th language if in the available language the `mediaaccess` not present then it should print `Untitled`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const findCompareValue = (type) => {
  const searchKey = compareObj[type]?.compare;

  const typeObject = result[type] ?? {};
  let compareValue = null;
  outer:
  for (key in typeObject) {
    const value = typeObject[key];
    for (subkey in value) {
      const subvalue = value[subkey];
      compareValue = subvalue[searchKey];
      if (compareValue != null)
        break outer;
    }
  }
  return compareValue ?? "Untitled";
};

console.log(findCompareValue("computer")); //"Some value here"
console.log(findCompareValue("fieldtest")); //"Untitled"
console.log(findCompareValue("testing")); //"system check"
```

You didn't explain what you were trying to do. The first key under the type seems like a language code. If that's the case, logic which extract a string value from the first language that contains it seems incorrect. If your question explained, at a higher level, what you are trying to achieve, the answers would probably be more useful to you.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/codebling/pen/eYydoRW?editors=0012)

Comment: if the multiple key having the same value then it should take the first obj value

Comment: @Vikas Code above takes first found value.

Comment: no it showing me Untitled everytime I pass value 
and I have one doubt can we remove that `findCompareValue` function just the logic part should be there

Comment: Why is it showing you "Untitled" every time? I am getting output "Some value here" for "computer". Are you getting the output that is listed at the end of the function?  Of course you can remove the function and keep the logic

Comment: Can you run add this code in code snippet please ? As in my system it was not running properly and showing me untitled everytime

Comment: @Vikas https://codepen.io/codebling/pen/eYydoRW?editors=0012

Comment: do I everytime pass the value through the function can I get this code without function please it would be really helpful to me

Comment: OK @Codebiling I am getting expected output but I am trying to remove the function but not able to return value `console.log(findCompareValue(display));` I have to pass value by this but I don't want to use function and I am passing `type` by using map function but how I gonna receive the output that's what I am trying to figuring out

Comment: @Vikas if you remove function, then `compareValue ?? "Untitled"` will be your output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576613/16041868 I have added ans in comment section can you check it please ?

Comment: done @codebiling and relax I won't run I just have some doubts that's why I am asking you

Comment: I added a comment on your other answer

Comment: Hi @Codebling can you help me in your code I have made some changes in the object can you help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71576613/16041868

Comment: @Vikas I see the changes. What is the issue? Can you describe in words what the new problem is, or perhaps ask a new question?

Comment: I am trying to get every value which matches the `compareObj` as by your help I am getting `some value here` but from `en-us 4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA` can I also get `test value` from `ksjdfsk123233165` but also check if the value not present in `en` then it should check in `hi` or `ja` but if not present inside any one then it should print `Untitled`

Comment: @Vikas this is what happens when the requirements are not clear, and we use imperative (hard to maintain) code. The logic is so nested and uncomprehensible that even the people who wrote it find it hard to make changes.

Comment: @Vikas open a new question if you want to rewrite. If you don't want to write and continue down this horrible path, change `break outer` to `console.log(compareValue ?? "Untitled")` and remove the other `console.log` line.

Comment: @Vikas I've made the edit for you in your own answer

Comment: If the value is null then it will print `Untitled` ? @Codebling because In `hardware` `en` and `us` having `66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW` `fieldtest` contain `null` value but it not showing me `Untitled` that's why I asked

Comment: @Vikas ok, maybe like that?

Comment: hi @codebling can you help him https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71639342/return-custom-object-by-modifying-the-object-using-javascript-node-js
by using your code he is trying to modify json can you help him where he is getting wrong?

Comment: @Vikas I already helped that friend [in their other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67711917/675721) and they did not even read my answer

Comment: He already solved that question and that's why I think he did not replied your answer 

Comment: Is there any possible way you can help  it would be really helpful to him 

Comment: @Vikas I will have take a look

Comment: can you help me so I can get only all the matching values even the value is present like you can see in `"testing": { "compare": "mediaaccess" }` and `mediaaccess` is present only in `"ja": {"2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA": {"mediaaccess": "system check",` but it is not present in `hi: {"2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA"` so if the value is null or not present then it should print `Untitled` and if it present then it should print there respected value ? please

Comment: @Vikas you've changed what the program is supposed to do since we started looking at this problem. I unfortunately don't have any more time to help. I highly suggest that you: 1) use a debugger to step through your code. This will help you understand what is happening and how to fix it 2) change the loop to iterate over `result` and not over `compareObj`

Answer (score 0):

```js
let result={
  "computer": {
    "en": {
      "4gSSbjCFEorYXqrgDIP2FA": {
        "gallery": "Some value here",
        "dummykey": "some dummy value here"
      },
      "ksjdfsk123233165":{
        "gallery": "test value",
        "dummykey": "checking the new file here"
      }
    }
  },
  "testing": {
    "hi": {
      "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA": {
        "access": "not available",
        "final": "still in progress"
      }
    },
    "ja": {
      "2pOUGnI1oRD7nsrYs600HA": {
        "mediaaccess": "system check",
        "access": "available",
        "final": "done"
      },
      "sdjksd9120812nmdns9": {
        "access": "available",
        "final": "progress"
      }
    }
  },
  "hardware": {
    "us": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "fieldtest": null,
        "media": "not available"
      },
      "sjkjsp3253m899as0": {
        "fieldtest": null,
        "media": "not available"
      }
    },
    "eu": {
      "66rzYr2BpWL1VTBHdLTdSW": {
        "fieldtest": null,
        "media": "available"
      },
      "sjkjsp3253m899as0": {
        "fieldtest": "in test we are planning",
        "media": "not available"
      }
    }
  },
  "software": {
    "uk": {
      "2eAmIIuG4xkLvatkU3RUSy": {
        "testfield": "its working",
        "assign": "not yet"
      },
      "wehjbe8230291929umsnd":{
        "testfield": "working",
        "assign": "new trainee"
      }
    }
  },
  "demo": {
    "ga": {
      "4zu7f2YP4cXqR6aeeMxEt8": {
        "newkey": "hello",
        "assign": "to new assignnie"
      },
      "ksdjfns4575634n":{
        "newkey": "working",
        "assign": "new trainee"
      }
    },
  }
};

let compareObj= {
  "computer": { "compare": "gallery" },
  "testing": { "compare": "mediaaccess" },
  "hardware": { "compare": "fieldtest" },
  "software": { "compare": "testfield" },
  "demo": { "compare": "assign" }
};

Object.keys(compareObj).map((type)=>{
const searchKey = compareObj[type]?.compare;

  const typeObject = result[type] ?? {};
  let compareValue;
  outer:
  for (key in typeObject) {
    const value = typeObject[key];
    compareValue = null;
    for (subkey in value) {
      const subvalue = value[subkey];
      compareValue = subvalue[searchKey];
      if (compareValue != null)
        break
    }
    console.log(compareValue ?? "Untitled")
  }
  
})
```

So I executed your code and In place of null I am getting null can I get Untitled in place of null ?

Comment: You need to assign `compareValue ?? "Untitled"` to a variable like `const final = compareValue ?? "Untitled"; console.log(final); `, this should work.

Comment: Is this working as you expect/wish? Is that all you needed? Let me know if you need explanation of certain lines or overall.

Comment: yes its working as expected thank you so much :)

Comment: One of my friend looking for this ans see if you can help him its totally up to you :) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67711917/add-new-json-object-if-id-match-with-json-id-of-other-using-node-js-javascript/71572850#71572850